# Как циклично просуммировать значения ячеек с помощью формул Google таблиц?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Нужно c помощью стандартных функций google таблиц (типа VLOOKUP) если это возможно, или функции query(), циклично просуммировать ячейки как показано на картинке и поместить суму в ячейку H2.

Опишу последовательность:

1. В столбце Н ищем ячейки в со значением 1 (на скрине H22, H23, H29).
2. Берем значения ячеек из столбца С (C22, C23, C29) умножаем их на соответсвующие значения ячеек H22, H23, H29.
3. Суммируем и сумму помещаем в ячейку H2.
4. То же самое мне нужно проделать с остальными столбцами.

То есть вот так: C22*H22+C23*H23+C29*H29 и всё это в H2.

Я не опытный пользователь Google таблиц и не программист. Я понимаю что нужен цикл какой то, но не знаю как реализовать. Мне нужен самый простой вариант.
Нужен какой то цикличный аналог функции VLOOKUP().

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 414+14+81 = 509, а не 428

Comment: Используйте функцию [=СУММЕСЛИМН()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=ru&sjid=8956965149764945894-EU#null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем множить на единицу?

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(H:H;1;C:C)
```

Для любого числового "флага", отличного от нуля:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(H:H;"<>";C:C)
```

Если в столбце `Н` может быть другое число и действительно нужна сумма произведений:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(H2:H99;C2:C99)
```

`СУММПРОИЗВ` прожорлива, для уменьшения лишних вычислений ей нужно указывать диапазон суммирования.